# How to change Wallpaper-preferences from nemo to nautilus

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, nemo

I have installed nemo instead of nautilus, and almost everything works fine, except one thing:
If I want to change the wallpaper and I use right-click - change wallpaper, a Cinnamon preferences window opens. If I change the wallpaper here, nothing happens...
I'd prefer the "old" wallpaper window from gnome/unity, which changes the wallpapers accordingly.
Can I change that "action"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know.. this happens because in the Nemo's source code when you click in **"Change Desktop Background"** execute the cinnamon-settings.

You can try to edit the source code to call the gnome-control-center instead cinnamon-setting.

**NOTE:** *In this example I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with Cinnamon Desktop & nemo 1.8.4 installed from the* [ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable) *ppa.*

### Download the Source Code, Edit & compile.

**1)** Edit the *gwendal-lebihan-dev-cinnamon-stable-raring.list* file to allow download the source code.

- `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gwendal-lebihan-dev-cinnamon-stable-raring.list`

Remove the **"#"** character.

**BEFORE:**

```
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable/ubuntu raring main
```

**AFTER:**

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable/ubuntu raring main
```

Save the changes in nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

- `sudo apt-get update`

**2)** Open a Terminal and install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

**3)** Install build dependencies.

- `sudo apt-get build-dep nemo`

**4)** Create a folder to download the source code.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src`

**5)** Download the source code.

- `apt-get source nemo`

**6)** Edit the file *"nemo-desktop-icon-view.c"*

- `gedit nemo-1.8.4-20130709192207/src/nemo-desktop-icon-view.c`

Search for the lines 665  & 667 to change them.

**BEFORE:**

```
"cinnamon-settings",  
"backgrounds", NULL);
```

[image]

**AFTER:**

```
"gnome-control-center",
"unity-appearance", NULL);
```

[image]

### Edit as per comment to remove "Add Desklets" action.

**7)** Edit the file *"nemo-desktop-icon-view-ui.xml"* to remove **"Add Desklets"** action.

Search for the line number "12" to delete it.

[image]

You can remove it with your favorite editor or with this command:

- `sed -i '/Desklets/d' ~/Downloads/src/nemo-1.8.4-20130709192207/src/nemo-desktop-icon-view-ui.xml`

**8)** Go to the *"nemo-1.8.4-20130709192207"* folder to build the deb packages.

- `cd nemo-1.8.4-20130709192207/`
- `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b`

**9)** Now you can install the deb packages.

- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i *deb`

**10)** Enable the "*gnome-control-center-unity-appearance.desktop*" file to appears in the gnome-control-center.

- `sudo sed -i.bak 's/OnlyShowIn=Unity;/OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;/g' /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center-unity-appearance.desktop`

**11)** Hide the "*gnome-background-panel.desktop*" file from the gnome-control-center.
 To avoid this:

[image]

- `sudo sed -i.bak 's/OnlyShowIn=GNOME;/NotShowIn=GNOME;/g' /usr/share/applications/gnome-background-panel.desktop`

**NOTE:** *with the "sed -i.bak" command, backups files will be created with the extension .bak*

**12)** Finally you can logout and Login to see the changes.

**The Result:**

[image]

[image]

As you can see the menu does not have the "Add Desklets" action and the "Change Desktop Background" will open the *gnome-control-center appearance*

Hope it helps.

Comment: one more thing: can I remove the Desklet-action which has no influence at all the same way?

Comment: Glad to help. I edited my asnwer to remove "add desklets" action.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the compile from source answer, but here's an alternate simpler solution for the less adventurous.

Recently in an article I found a patched version of Nemo, which does not require Cinnamon dependencies. This version does this by default.

To install it, fire up your terminal, and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

That's it. This PPA also has extensions for Nemo, which I missed from the one from the 13.10 default repos. To install them:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-compare nemo-dropbox nemo-media-columns nemo-pastebin nemo-seahorse nemo-share

# If you need it
sudo apt-get install nemo-rabbitvcs

# Terminal inside Nemo
sudo apt-get install nemo-terminal
```

On how to set Nemo as default and such... I don't think it belongs here, but future readers can find it in the original article here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html