# Change Desktop Background does not work in 14.04

Tags: 14.04

The usual desktop right click -> `Change Desktop Background` option does not open the wallpapers dialog box. This may be unrelated, but I installed the `Nemo` package.

The following is the result of `uname -a` : 
`Linux konoha 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Tried restarting the system and the problem persists.
Should this be raised as a bug in launchpad ?

Comment: Are you able to open it by other means? Such as searching for Background in the Dash, clicking on the gear icon in the top right and selecting System Settings, etc.?

Comment: The `System Settings` is still in tact. I can also open the `Appearance` Settings from the dash as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely due to Nemo. I suspect that `nemo` is now handling your desktop, and it tries to open Cinnamon's settings instead of Unity's, according to [How to change Wallpaper-preferences from nemo to nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343819/how-to-change-wallpaper-preferences-from-nemo-to-nautilus).

This [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217010&p=12990735#post12990735) has a solution:

- If you update nemo using [the ppa from webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html), this is fixed.
- If you don't want to use the PPA you can try adding [this file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8305571/) as `change-background2.nemo_action` to `~/.local/share/nemo/actions/`. 
  It works but you still have the old "Change Background" entry as well.

There's also the third option: compiling from source, which is discussed in the question I linked to in the first paragraph.

If you want to file a bug, file it with [Nemo](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nemo/+filebug). It used to be that `cinnamon` was a dependency of Nemo, but that was fixed, but it looks like some dangling ends are left.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this command worked for:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```