# File browser freezes in certain folders

Tags: unity, nautilus, desktop-background, cinnamon, nemo

Nautilus crashes when I access folders with certain files: the window does not respond anymore, and I do not see the contents of the folder. If I move the files (e.g. from the terminal), I can open the folders with no problem; however, I still cannot open the new folder with the respective files.

I also shared these files with someone, and they did not have the problem (their nautilus did not freeze).

I already tried the following:

- [run nautilus as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446401/nautilus-crashes-accessing-a-certain-folder)
- [remove nautilus config files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64244/nautilus-crashes-when-accessing-some-folders)
- [remove nautilus-open-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64244/nautilus-crashes-when-accessing-some-folders)
- [install nemo as default browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605275/how-to-set-nemo-as-default-instead-of-nautilus/605283?noredirect=1#comment1283394_605283): this helped, however, I could not set my wallpaper anymore with Nemo as default browser. I [found that people had similar problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343819/how-to-change-wallpaper-preferences-from-nemo-to-nautilus?rq=1), so I installed a version that did not require cinnamon dependencies ([ppa:webupd8team/nemo3](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/11/nemo-320-with-unity-patches-and-without.html)). However, with this version of Nemo, I have again the same problem: Nemo now crashes in the same folders as Nautilus does.

Comment: What kind of files are we talking about, specific names? extensions?

Comment: Have you analysed what specific files or directories makes Nautilus freeze ?

Comment: Nautilus opens certain files to generate previews. That might cause problems. Try to turn off (or limit) Previews: Edit --> Preferences --> Preview

Comment: did not help unfortunately

Comment: Hi BN, did you notice my question for additional info? In the meantime you *did* mention suggested solutions did not work, so I assume you read it?

Comment: (weird the comment about previews was an answer on which I commented that it did not work; I hadn't seen your comment yet) PDF files (I don't know whether it happens for other files as well)